# Fundamental group of theta-space and the doubly punctured theta space in Munkres Topology Example 70.1

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-product

Munkres Topology Example 70.1

[image]

[image]

Let X be theta-space, U = $X \setminus \{a\}$ and V = $X \setminus \{b\}$. Let $U \cap V = X \setminus \{a,b\}$ be doubly punctured theta-space where $a,b$ are interior points of $A$ and $B$.

1. **Why is doubly punctured theta-space contractible**? I think it has the homotopy type of a point, possibly the center of $X$. I have 3 or 4 solutions to this that I am trying to work through.
2. **Why does $B \cup C$ have the same homotopy type as $U$?** I think of "deformation retract implies same homotopy type", but I think it's not even a retract. It appears that it's going to be that I have to directly prove that they have the same homotopy type by thinking of the explicit homotopy equivalences instead of deducing implicit homotopy equivalences from proving one $B \cup C$ is a deformation retract or homeomorphic space to $U$. Other comments would be welcomed.

**For now, please just give me hints, and I can work out the details on my own.** This is so I don't spend a lot of time going down dead paths since this problem has been done before. When I get into a PhD, I can go down dead paths. Now, I would rather know the answer and work towards it, of course now that I've seen some paths and went down one dead path.

---

Update:

I think

1. $\{0\}$ is a deformation retract of $C$, and $C$ is a deformation retract of $X \setminus \{a,b\}$.

Proof uses the retractions $r_1(z)=z1_C+Re(z)1_{[A \setminus \{a\}] \cup [B \setminus \{b\}]}$ from $X \setminus \{a,b\}$ onto $C$, which is continuous by the pasting lemma and $r_2(z)=0$ from $C$ onto $\{0\}$ and the straight line homotopies $H_1(z,t)=z(1-t)+tr_1(z)$ and $H_2(z,t)=z(1-t)$ because $H_1(c,t)=c, c \in C$ and $H_2(0,t)=0$.

2. $B \cup C$ is a [deformation retract](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2996688) of $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part 1, if you remove a point from the arcs A and B, can we deform the the line segments to anything?

For part 2, just remove the point from arc A and see what space you get after deformation.

Comment: This is perfect Joel Pereira thank you! Another hint for part 2 please? Do you mean $B \cup C$ may or may not be a deformation retract of $U$, but if it's not a deformation retract, it could be the same homotopy type as a deformation retract of $U$? This is so genius!

Comment: I think I figured it out and updated my question. Is this correct, Joel Pereira?

Comment: @JackBauer Yes that's it. Good job.

Comment: Thank you so much!