# Prove that doubly punctured theta space is contractible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-product

This is a different approach to what was suggested by Joel Pereira in my question [Fundamental group of theta-space and the doubly punctured theta space in Munkres Topology Example 70.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993700)

Munkres Topology Example 70.1

[image]

[image]

Let X be theta-space, U = $X \setminus \{a\}$ and V = $X \setminus \{b\}$. Let $U \cap V = X \setminus \{a,b\}$ be doubly punctured theta-space where $a,b$ are interior points of $A$ and $B$.

The doubly punctured space $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{p,q\}$ has deformation retracts Figure 8 and $X$. I think the Figure 8 for $p=(-1,0)$ and $q=(1,0)$ is or can be 2 circles centered at $p$ and $q$ that intersect only at the origin $(0,0)$. If Figure 8 has the same homotopy type as $\{(0,0)\}$ and $X$ has the same homotopy type as $X \setminus \{a,b\}$, then $X \setminus \{a,b\}$ has the same homotopy type as $\{(0,0)\}$.

1. Is this argument (not necessarily its assumptions!) right?
2. Does Figure 8 have the same homotopy type as $\{(0,0)\}$?
3. Does $X$ have the same homotopy type as $X \setminus \{a,b\}$?

If the answers are all yes, I can work out the details on my own, and you can just say so in an answer without explanation and then I'll accept your answer.

If the answer to 1 is no, then why?

If the answer to 1 is yes but the answer to 2 or 3 is no, then again you can just say so in an answer without explanation and then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: $X$ does not have the same homotopy type of $X \setminus \{a,b\}$, because the latter is contractible. You should be able to prove on your own that $X \setminus \{a,b\}$ is homeomorphic to the letter $H$ with the endpoints of the vertical bars removed. Now construct a deformation retraction to the point by first crushing the vertical bars and then crushing the horizontal line.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thank you! Can you help me here please? [Fundamental group of theta-space and the doubly punctured theta space in Munkres Topology Example 70.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993700)