# Covering space of "theta space" by another subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I wish to either describe the covering map $p : X \to Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ shown, or give a reason why such a cover does not exist.

[image: Problem image]

I have found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993700/fundamental-group-of-theta-space-and-the-doubly-punctured-theta-space-in-munkres), that $Y$, often referred to as the "theta space" or "theta graph," has $\pi_1(Y)\cong \langle a,b \rangle$.

Something tells me that $Y \simeq \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$... Is $X \simeq \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$? If yes to both, this begs the question: does any bouquet of circles $\bigvee_i \mathbb{S}^1_i$? cover $\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$? I am doubtful, since I don't recall seeing this as one of the examples in Hatcher AT, but I can sometimes be the forgetful student.

When I first looked at this, I approached it as follows: Suppose $p$ is a covering map, then $p$ is a local homeomorphism. So there exists an open neighborhood $U$ in $X$ centered at $x$ (pictured) such that $p(U)$ is open in $Y$ and $p|_U:U\to p(U)$ is a homeomorphism. Openness seems to be fine (with respect to the topologies of $X$ of $Y$ induced by $\mathbb{R}^2$). However, $U-\{x\}$ has $4$ connected components, while any neighborhood in $Y$ remove any point has either $3$ or $2$ connected components. Thus, $p|_U$ is not a homeomorphism.

If this argument is invalid, where precisely is its flaw? I could really use some help on this.

Comment: I don't think $Y$ is $S^1\lor S^1$, since the two "circles" share an entire arc, not just a point. The argument in the later paragraph looks good to me.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. So we cannot homotope that shared arc to a point? With homotopy one can pull off some wild things. What is the reason for this precisely? Is there a continuity issue? I'm not quite seeing it. It's very interesting to me that nevertheless $\pi_1(Y) \cong \pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1)$.

Comment: In a CW-complex we can identify contractible subcomplexes to a point and get a CW-complex of the same homotopy type. This allows to compute the fundamental groups of $X,Y$. But this information does not help us. Your argument concerning the non-existence of a local homeomorphism is fine.

Comment: @contingent That idea is more related to the notion of homotopy equivalence, which is a valuable tool. But for actual homeomorphisms, the arc is not a point (and your later argument also works to distinguish them here).

Comment: I see, great, thank you both!